# Keep randomly positioned images in constant position in Meteor + Handlebars. Possible {{#constant}} issue

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

Im having some trouble with keeping some randomly placed images (lets say balloons) in constant positions, while using Meteor (and Handlebars).

The images randomize position correctly using this:

```
Template.main.random = function(from,to) {
return Math.floor(Math.random()*(to-from+1)+from);
},
```

And html:

```
{{#each images user.balloons}}
    {{#constant}}
        <img class="itemimage" src="{{url}}" style="margin-left:{{random 1 200}}px; margin-top:{{random 1 100}}px;">
    {{/constant}}
{{/each}}
```

However the {{#consant}} doesnt work as i'd hoped; the images receive new random margins every update, so they skip around all over the show! Is there a way to keep them from being updated? Am i using {{#constant}} incorrectly?

Any help is much appreciated! Its my first project and going well, so im keen to keep momentum.

Thanks!

edit: a quick note, when i tried moving the {{#constant}} outside the {{#each}}, the images didnt show at all, so thats a no go.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as it says in the docs:

> Constant regions are intended for embedding non-Meteor content. Event handlers and reactive dependencies don't currently work correctly inside constant regions.

I'd suggest writing some function which produces an array of random coordinates of the appropriate size and then running this first in the client side code and storing the result in a normal javascript variable.  Then, just add a helper to the template in which you're rendering the balloons to supply the relevant coordinates for each one.  That should keep them in place unless the user does a hard refresh.

Comment: Damn. That sounds... complicated. So theres no way to set their coords and leave them? Thanks for your answer though!